# Populating MySQLi result into a PHP indexed array

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to load result of a mysqli select statement (single field with multiple rows) into an array like:

```
$post = [318,310,323]
```

As you can see I used the `fetch_array()`:

```
$posts = [];
 .....
$stmt->bind_param("s", $sessien);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
       {
            array_push($posts, $row);
       }
print_r($posts );

$result->free();
$stmt->close();
$customconn->close();
```

but on printing r the `$posts` is creating something like this (looks like an array in array):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 318
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 310
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 323
        )

)
```

How can I fix this to have something like:

```
$post = [318,310,323]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`mysqli_result::fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) will always return an array - even for 1 field, you need to add that field rather than the entire result to your overall result array...

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)
array_push($posts, $row[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `array_push($posts, $row[0])`;

Or you can call `array_column` on your result.

> array_column($posts, 0)

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 8.1, this became much easier. All you have to do is call `fetch_column()` and collect the elements into an array.

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($id = $result->fetch_column()) {
    $posts[] = $id;
}
```